# Illustrator - Stroke after 3d Effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, stroke

i apologize if my question is too immature but i just cant figure it out. i'm new to illustrator and i want a black stroke around all my objects but i cant give it to objects that have 3D effects applied to them (like the sphere in the attached image). tried Rasterizing and expanding but no result. thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3D Effect objects take a couple of special steps in order to add a stroke effectively.

Select the object with the 3D Effect applied and choose `Object > Group`.

In the **Appearance Panel**, add a `New Stroke` and then move that `Stroke` so it is below the `Contents`.

Highlight the stroke in the **Appearance Panel** and choose `Effect > Pathfinder > Add`

You should then be able to change the color and weight of the stroke to your liking.

[image]

Note the `Group` is important because otherwise the stroke will be applied to *only* the original object minus the 3D effect. The `Add` effect is important otherwise the stroke is applied to all blend steps within the 3D object and not the object as a whole. I can't state *why* strokes are so odd on 3D objects, but this should be a sufficient workaround.

Comment: Cool, thank you for the quick answer. it was very helpful.